# QInputDialog doesn't show title and border in android application

Tags: android, qt, qt-necessitas

I've wrote a simple slot function to show an inputdialog. But it appears as below in android emulator. The code is :

```
void PriceChecker::showSettings()
{
    QInputDialog UrlDialog;
    QString baseUrl = UrlDialog.getText(m_pMainWidget, "Settings", "Enter BaseURL");    
}
```

[image: Application window]

[image: When Dialog appears in application window]

Can someone tell why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

It does this for all QDialog-based widget being displayed. They never have border nor title bar...except QMessageBox.

- Create and display a `QMessageBox` -> this shows with title and border
- Create and display a `QInputDialog` -> this shows with no title and border
- Create and display a `QDialog` -> this shows with no title and border

I workarounded the problem by catching `QEvent::ShowToParent` event in `QApplication::notify` and making dialog about to be displayed size fit main frame size, it then covers the whole screen. At least controls are not mixed with the main frame controls....

Note: I submitted this Qtbug: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39623

Answer (score 0):

... either it's a problem of the customized style of my host application (since i'm doing a plugin), or it's the same on windows;

anyway it can be easily worked around by explicitly setting the window flags like:

```
QInputDialog d;
Qt::WindowFlags f = d.windowFlags();
f |= Qt::Dialog;
d.setWindowFlags(f);
```